# 'npm run dev' not showing Event line on cmd, and localhost stuck on loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cmd, nodes

Any suggestions will be appreciated!(and yes, I am new to this).

I have tried cleaning cache, turning off firewall, restarting PC, Reinstalling Nodejs, I have even restarted the project from scratch but still this issue has not been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
this is what I see and localhost never load, it is usefully that I say that my project is with `prisma client` and `nextjs`

```
control_interno@0.1.0 dev
next dev
```

---

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from D:\Dayana\TRABAJO\ICIMAF\Control INterno\control-interno\.env
```